# recursive function to search in json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function in javascript but not work properly. i have a json array of objects data where i want to find something based on key then find again based on gotopage key in search object.

like : find orange -> gotopage -> orange_store ->find -> orange_store -> gotopage -> yellow_store -> find so the same process goes in recursively.can you please help where i'm going wrong in my approach.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "find": "orange",
        "gotopage": "orange_store"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "find": "orange_store",
        "gotopage": "yellow_store"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "find": "black_store",
        "gotopage": "black_store"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "find": "yellow_store",
        "gotopage": "white_store"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "find": "black_store",
        "gotopage": "red_store"
    }
]


function searchRec(search, myArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        var res = [];
        if (myArray[i].find == search) {
            if (myArray[i] !== null) {
                console.log(myArray[i]);
                res = searchRec(myArray[i].gotopage, myArray);
                if (res !== null) {
                    return res;
                }
                return myArray[i];
            }

        }
    }
}

function findNode(arr) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        searchRec(arr[i].find, arr);
        break;
    }
}
console.log(findNode(json));
```

output for first iteration but not work for every iteration:

```
Object {id: 1, find: "orange", gotopage: "orange_store"}
Object {id: 2, find: "orange_store", gotopage: "yellow_store"}
```

Comment: Why is the third object not find:yellow_store?

Comment: You're checking for null returned from `searchRec` but never returning null. In javascript, indexing a missing element in an array will yield `undefined` not `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Another example using recursion. I do a simple `forEach()` to find what you're looking for and store it in variables, log it, and re-call the function with our newly created values. If it doesn't find anything, it returns null and ends.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "find": "orange",
        "gotopage": "orange_store"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "find": "orange_store",
        "gotopage": "yellow_store"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "find": "black_store",
        "gotopage": "black_store"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "find": "yellow_store",
        "gotopage": "white_store"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "find": "black_store",
        "gotopage": "red_store"
    }
];

function recursiveStore(search, myArray) {
    let obj = {}
    let newSearch;
    data.forEach(store => {
      if (search === store.find) {
        obj = store
        newSearch = store.gotopage 
      } 
    })
    if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
        return null
    }
    console.log(obj)
    recursiveStore(newSearch, myArray)
}

recursiveStore("orange", data)
```

Comment: thanks @christopher for best solution. i want to return obj instead of console.log ?

Comment: which object? all of them?

Comment: you wrote console.log(obj) after recursive function will call but what if i return instead of console.log.

Comment: if you wrote `return` instead - it would end there and not re-run itself. A function can only `return` one thing. You could do a couple of different things, like create an array outside of the object called `stores` and do something like `stores.push(obj)` instead of `console.log(obj)` and then still return `recursiveStore(newSearch, myArray)` and by the end, you'll have all the stores you need in one array of objects.